# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, include, iostream

I've reinstalled Visual Studio 2010 Professional several times to try to get it to work.
I had to uninstall Visual Studio 2012 Professional because it wasn't compiling something we did in class.

I completely uninstalled everything including SQL Server..

I went to VC/include and the iostream header file is not there.

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {

cout << "hello";

system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

This is all I'm trying to do because nothing else is working.

It's really driving me crazy because I need to get it working so that I can do my project!!!

Every time I do; new project => empty project => add an item to source =>.cpp

I'm running windows 8.

It just says Error cannot open source file
Also, error cout identifier is undefined....

I'm wondering if I should do a system restore?
Or if I should just completely reinstall windows 8 from my recovery media?

Answer (score 5):

One problem is that you did not include the namespace `std`.

This is what your code should look like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (void) {
    cout << "hello" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

or you could have done something like this: `std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;`

This may be a problem because you did not set your environment to C++. This is how you do it:

1. Go to *Tools* > *Import and Export settings*. If you cannot find it, just search for it in Quick Search
2. Then go to reset all settings.
3. Then simply select "Visual C++"
4. Restart.

That should do the trick. If it does not, you might consider re-installing Visual C++ itself. For [VS 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679). If that does not work, then re-install the program.

Comment: In visual studio 2012 this doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score -2):

if it is problem with visual studio 2012, install [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305) update.

Comment: This should be a comment when you are not sure about problem

Comment: @WoodChopper, `using namespace std;` is the first thing to do, if that does not fix the problem,then trying this update might help. I wanted to comment on the above answer, couldn't do because i don't have enough reputations.

Comment: @WoodChopper: That is not so. An answer is an answer is an answer; whether you are "sure" about it or not does not change that. And answers should **never** be written as comments. However, _this_ is just a link, not an answer, and was not worth posting at all.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit : My bad, I meant if he is not clear about question/problem what op is facing he could ask that in comment.

Comment: @WoodChopper: Ah, got ya.