# What are the standard include paths for MS Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to build a hello-world C++ application using Microsoft Visual C++.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello, world. " << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

> main.cpp(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such file or directory

What are the standard include paths for Microsoft Visual C++?

*Note: I am building from the command-line, not from Visual Studio*

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx

Comment: Visual C++ command-line build tools require several environment variables. I would recommend using the visual studio Developer Command prompt that is included in installation. Otherwise look at the DevEnv command line switch. Tip: show an example of the command you are running.

Comment: The path of iostream should be in the Properties of your project— Menu Project > Properties / Configuration Properties / VC++ Directories — The entry "Include Directories" should contain `$(VC_IncludePath)` ,which in turn should be something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include` — You can inspect its value entering lhe little dropdown at the right and choose "Edit...". It should not even be a problem if you created your project using the respective wizard,

Comment: This looks like a duplicate...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181537/fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-iostream-no-such-file-or-directo OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713842/visual-c-cant-open-include-file-iostream OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713842/visual-c-cant-open-include-file-iostream/24173437  Just Saying.

Comment: do you have Visual Studio and the optional Visual C++ components Installed?  Both of them?  OR the Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools?   can't run Visual C++ code in a plain command prompt window.   find out if the stuff you need is there open a developer command prompt window and type in 'c1' hit enter and the system should feed back that  'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>cl  
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23918 for x86  
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.  

usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]  '

Answer (score 0):

I actually just read through all of the documentation on this at:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639.aspx

The material looks detailed and complete.  If you get things configured like they require then it must work.  They provide plenty of checks and conditions for ensuring that you are set up properly.

I am seriously suspecting that you aren't using a **developer command prompt** window.

I just did it myself and it works.  Use Notepad and name the files like they tell you to do.

"Hello world!!"

Comment: I am not using developer command prompt. Is this a requirement? Can I just set the paths like with Clang / GCC (using a different syntax, of course) `clang -I etc... `

Comment: according to to MSDN the developer command prompt/window is a must.  i couldnt imagine all the links youd need otherwise